# Structure in structure and pointer in function argument

Tags: c++

```
struct _s1 
        {
            uint32_t var1; 
            struct _s2 
            {
                uint32_t var2;
                uint32_t var3; 
            } s2;
        }
        struct _s1 s1;
```

It is possible to have a pointer to structure s1 and f.e. use variables from imbedded structure s2 and mainly s1:

```
void funcS(_s1 *sTest) 
{
    sTest->var1 = 1; 
    sTest->s2.var2 = 4; 
}
```

The question: it is possible to have pointer in "funcS" argument only refer to "s2" structure and be unable to use var1 f.e. (and others types from s1)?

```
void funkcS(_s1->s2 *s2Test)
```

- it won't work posted only for reference. It have to be compiled in c++11 and C11.
  Thanks for any advice.

Comment: The answer to your question depends *very* much on language. So please pick *one* language.

Comment: C and C++ are **different** languages. This is C++ code, not C. "It have to be compiled in c++11 and C11" does not make sense.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite It have sense, especially if new library have to be portable between embedded systems in C11 standard and embedded applications with OS (f.e. Linux) written in C++.... Ofcourse not all operations from C are allowed in C++ and vice versa.

Comment: @Fasset: Reducing to the exactly compatible set is a very bad approach as the set is much smaller than you might think. Just that: identical syntax does not imply identical semantics. Why not use one language on both systems, maybe a C++ wrapper/header. You **are** aware you can link C and C++ code, are you?

Comment: @toohonestforthissite I know C++ is more rigorous f.e. if it concern pointers but mostly compiled source in C++ should compiled in C too. Yes, using C++ on both systems would be better but the main problem is not compatibility between C++ and some provided library (HAL  - stm32) - it wouldn't be problem to write it using low level registers configuration exclude USB which is required.

Comment: If you use that ST HAL crap, you are lost anyway. That bloatware just makes the code more complicated writing and - worse debugging. It eats up cycles for nothing. Nevertheless it's not what I meant. Please read my comments **carefully and completely**. What you try is definitively not recommended practice. I leave this here, you have to do a lot of reading I'd say.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite I know - I am using HAL only for USB - write own driver for USB is madness.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the scope-operator `::` to reach nested scopes, as in `_s1::_s2`:

```
void func2(_s1::_s2* ptr) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either pointers or references. I also would recommend defining the struct s2 outside s1.

```
#define uint32_t int

struct s2{
    uint32_t var2;
    uint32_t var3;
};

struct s1{
    uint32_t var1;
    s2 _s2;
};

void funcS(s1 *sTest)
{
    sTest->var1 = 1;
    sTest->_s2.var2 = 4;
}

void funcSs2(s2 *sTest)
{
    sTest->var2 = 4;
}

void funcSs2ref(s2& sTest)
{
    sTest.var2 = 4;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  s1 obj;
  funcSs2(&obj._s2);
  funcSs2ref(obj._s2);
  return 0;
}
```